# Pass navigation.navigate to Child Component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Building an app using react-navigation. I have a parent component that pulls from firebase and renders data in a listview. The listview render component 'ListName' has an onRowPress function but this.props.navigation.navigate comes up undefined because navigation is not in that child component's state.

Ive tried multiple ways of passing in navigation prop to the child and also importing navigation from react-navigation within the child.  Nothing works.

Thanks!

Here is my rootStackNavigator:

```
const RootStackNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
    Main: { screen: MainTabNavigator },
    Feedback: { screen: ProvideInstanceScreen }
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      //headerTitleStyle: {
        //fontWeight: 'normal',
        tabBarVisible: false,
        header: null
      //},
    }),
  }
);
```

Here is my Parent Component (which has navigation.navigate in its state)

```
import React from 'react';
import { ListView, StyleSheet, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { MainButton, GenSection } from '../components/common';
import { namesFetch } from '../actions';
import ListName from '../components/ListName.js';

class ProvideScreen extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };


  componentWillMount() {
  //console.log('HOME HOME HOME  PRINT', this.props)
    this.props.namesFetch();

    this.createDataSource(this.props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('PROVIDE PROPS   PRINT', this.props)
    this.createDataSource(this.props);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    //nextProps are next set of props component is rendered with and this.props is still old props
    console.log('NEXT PROPS', nextProps)
    this.createDataSource(nextProps);
  }


  createDataSource({ names }) {
    var namesArray = names.map(function(a) {return [a.name, a.uid];});
    //console.log('NAMES ARRAY PRINT', namesArray)
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });
    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(namesArray);
  }

  renderRow(user) {
    return <ListName name={user[0]} />;
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <Image
        source={require('../components/images/mainBG.png')}
        style={styles.containerStyle}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
          Provide Feedback
        </Text>
        <GenSection style={{paddingTop: 8}} />
        <ListView
          enableEmptySections
          dataSource={this.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
          removeClippedSubviews={false}
        />

    </Image>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  containerStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
    backgroundColor:'transparent'
  },
  textStyle:
  {
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingLeft: 12,
    fontSize: 32,
    fontWeight: '200',
    color: '#597abc'
  }
});



const mapStateToProps = state => {
  //console.log('STATE PRINT', state.feedbackInput)
  const names = _.map(state.feedbackInput, (val) => {
    return { ...val};
  });
  //console.log('NAMES PRINT', names)
  return { names };
};  //this is lodash   .map iterates over key value pairs and run function which assigns data to groups array



export default connect(mapStateToProps, { namesFetch })(ProvideScreen);
```

Here is my child component (which does not have navigation.navigate in state):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback, View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ListButton } from './common';

class ListName extends Component {
  onRowPress() {
    console.log('ON ROW PRESS  PRINT', this.props)
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Feedback', this.props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //console.log('LIST NAME LIST NAME  PRINT', this.props)
  }

  render() {
    const name = this.props.name;
    //console.log('LISTNAME PRINT', name)

    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.onRowPress.bind(this)}>
        <View>
          <ListButton>
            <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>
              {name}
            </Text>
          </ListButton>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  titleStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '600',
  }
};


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  //console.log('NAMES PRINT', names)
  return state
};  //this is lodash   .map iterates over key value pairs and run function which assigns data to groups array


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ListName);
```

Answer (score 11):

Base on React Navigation:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html

You just need to import withNavigation into child component only.

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
```

then export:

```
export default withNavigation(<YourChildComponent>);
```

Answer (score 6):

i just add this prop from parent and it worked:

```
<AppFooter navigation={this.props.navigation}  />
```

Comment: It works for me, What if I have many childs should I add this to every child ?

Answer (score 5):

One way is to have a onPress handler in your `ProvideScreen` component that is passed down to your list item component and thus in `ProvideScreen`'s onRowPress function, you will have access to `this.props.navigation`.

In `ProvideScreen`:

```
class ProvideScreen extends Component {
  ...
  onRowPress(someRowData) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Feedback', { someRowData });
  }
  ...

  renderRow(user) {
    return <ListName name={user[0]} onRowPress={this.onRowPress} />;
  }
}
```

In `ListName`:

```
class ListName extends Component {
  ...
  onRowPress() {
    this.props.onRowPress(someData);
  }
  ...
}
```

Of course, don't forget about binding the functions to `this` scope when you are using event handlers.
e.g. in constructor:

```
this.onRowPress = this.onRowPress.bind(this);
```

An alternative define `onRowPress` with an arrow functions:

```
onRowPress = () => {
 this.props.navigation.navigate...
}
```

Comment: thank you! however I could not get it to work, either way.  I learned some new code though!    onRowPress is undefined in ListName props

Comment: What part is not working? I can still help if you give some detail on what you have tried

Comment: i appreciate it.  i put in just what you suggested above - both methods.  with both, the function is passed as a prop to the ListName component, but it is undefined.  thanks

Comment: im going to next attempt to call an action creator that returns a state variable switched true, which will trigger the navigation.navigate

Comment: sorry. id have to rebuild it (after it didnt work I tired pulling ListName into ProvideScreen)  Ill be back tomorrow.  thanks!!

Comment: Hi, I am new to react and javascript, would you mind to explain 'Of course, don't forget about binding the functions to this scope when you are using event handlers. e.g. in constructor'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036405/npm-start-not-working-in-reactjs-if-public-folder-is-inside-another-folder please answer my question in that link

Answer (score 1):

Pass all props like

Form

```
{...this.props}
```

here `<Form>` is my child components

other wise.

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
```

Then in the end

```
export default withNavigation(<ChildComponentName>);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass the navigation prop from the parent to the child directly by doing this:

```
renderRow(user) {
    return <ListName name={user[0]} navigation={this.props.navigation}/>;
}
```

This will allow you to use react-navigation's navigate method in ListName.

Info also from this page: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';

class Parent extends Component{
  <Child {...this.props}/>
}

class Child extends Component {
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate("Screen")}>
    <V><T>
     {PRESS ME}
    </V></T>
  </TouchableOpacity>
}

export default withNavigation(Parent);
```