# react native - Passing navigation props from parent to child

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to create a simple-ish mobile app, but I'm pretty new to this. I've spent some time searching about the errors I'm getting. It seems like a common problem, but they all had the same/similar solutions but the solutions didn't work for me.

What is I'm trying to do? Right now the app is two pages, the home screen (Overview Cards) and the Add Card screen.

1. There's a button on the Overview Cards that takes you to Add Card.
2. Add Card allows you to fill out some TextInput boxes and
3. Add Card *should* allow you to press the save button and be taken back to the Overview Card screen and see the data you entered in the form.

However, I am getting stuck at Step 3. I am trying to make the Save button navigate the user back to Overview Cards, but there are simply errors instead.

Below is my code, the errors I'm getting, and then what I've tried.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, Button, TouchableOpacity, ShadowPropTypesIOS } from 'react-native';
import AddCard from './components/AddCard.js';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.homeContainer}>
      <Button title="Add Card" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Add Card')}/>
      {/* <Text value={this.props.inputValFT}/> */}
      <Text style={styles.textStyle} >VISA xxxx</Text>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>MASTERCARD xxxx</Text>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>AMEX xxxx</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function AddCardScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.addCardContainer}>
      <AddCard navigation={this.props.navigation} /> // **HERE**
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ title: 'Overview Cards' }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Add Card" component={AddCardScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
// function AddCardButton(){
//       return (
//           <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
//               <TouchableOpacity>
//                   <Text style={styles.button}>Add Card</Text>
//               </TouchableOpacity>
//           </View>
//       );
//   }

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  homeContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ef95b1',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
  addCardContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#28cdf0',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    marginTop: 15,
  },
  button: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    marginTop: 15,
    right: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#2565ae',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 12,
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    padding: 10,
    textAlign:'center',
  },
  textStyle: {
    padding: 10,
  }
});
```

Navigation.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import AddCardScreen from './AddCard';

  const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: HomeScreen,
      AddCard: AddCardScreen,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
    }
  );

  const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#ef95b1',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    },
    textStyle: {
      padding: 10,
    }
  });

  export default createAppContainer(Navigation);
```

AddCard.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Input } from 'react-native-elements'
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

// import { loadSettings, saveSettings } from '../storage/settingsStorage';

class AddCardScreen extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        firstTwo  : '',
        lastFour  : '',
        recentAmt : ''
    };

    this.addFT = this.addFT.bind(this)
    this.addLF = this.addLF.bind(this)
    this.addRecAmt = this.addRecAmt.bind(this)
   }

   static navigationOptions = {
       title: 'Add Card'
    };

   addFT(firstTwo) {
    this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state.firstTwo, { firstTwo }));
  }

  addLF(lastFour) {
    this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state.lastFour, { lastFour }));
  }

  addRecAmt(recentAmt) {
    this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state.recentAmt, { recentAmt }));
  }

  // handleSubmit() {
  //  alert('New card saved. Returning to Home to view addition.');
  //  navigation.navigate('Home')
  // } // firstTwo, lastFour, recentAmt

    render() {
        const {navigation} = this.props;
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                    <Text h1> "Add a new card!" </Text> 
                    <TextInput 
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    placeholder="First two digits of card"
                    placeholderTextColor="#000000"
                    keyboardType={'number-pad'}
                    maxLength = {2}

                    onChangeText={this.addFT}
                    inputValFT={this.state.firstTwo}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    placeholder="Last four digits of card"
                    placeholderTextColor="#000000"
                    keyboardType={'number-pad'}
                    maxLength = {4}

                    onChangeText={this.addLF}
                    inputValLF={this.state.lastFour}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    placeholder="Most recent dollar amount"
                    placeholderTextColor="#000000"
                    keyboardType={'decimal-pad'}

                    onChangeText={this.addRecAmt}
                    inputValRA={this.state.recentAmt}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity 
                    style={styles.saveButton}
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}> // ** HERE 2 **
                        <Text style={styles.saveButtonText}>Save</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
// this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
export default AddCardScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    inputContainer: {
        paddingTop: 15
      },
      textInput: {
        borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
        textAlign: 'center',
        borderTopWidth: 1,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        height: 50,
        fontSize: 17,
        paddingLeft: 20,
        paddingRight: 20
      },
      saveButton: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#007BFF',
        backgroundColor: '#007BFF',
        padding: 15,
        margin: 5
      },
      saveButtonText: {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center'
      }

});
```

**The errors I'm getting:**

In App.js you can see the ** HERE ** that I put in. When I try to run this, the app loads fine until I click the "Add Card" button. I get this error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')`.

If I take the `navigate={this.props.navigation}` part out from App.js, the app loads as it's meant to again, but this time I can click the "Add Card" button and reach the next screen with no issue. I fill out the form (TextInput parts in AddCard.js), but when I click the "Save" button, the app crashes. The error is: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')`. Most likely because of what I'm doing with onPress where it says ** HERE 2 ** in AddCard.js. handleSubmit() is currently commented out, but it used to be inside the onPress.

**What I've tried:**

Some of the answers I saw were that I need to pass in navigation from the parent to the child and that will make it work. By trying that, I get the errors I mentioned earlier. I also saw that someone mentioned using "withNavigation" or "useNavigation" which was supposed to allow the child to access navigation, but that didn't work for me either.  Below are some of the links that I was trying to follow.

[How do I pass navigation props from parent component to header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48203708/how-do-i-pass-navigation-props-from-parent-component-to-header)

[Pass navigation.navigate to Child Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222149/pass-navigation-navigate-to-child-component)

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/

Thank you for reading, hopefully my explanation is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is somewhere here:

```
function AddCardScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.addCardContainer}>
      <AddCard navigation={navigation} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

- There is no `this`, you're not in a class component, therefore `this` doesn't exists
- The prop you are trying to pass should be called `navigation` and not `navigate`, since that's how you try to access it in the child component.
- The `navigation` prop needs to be destructured inside the function argument `function AddCardScreen({ navigation })`, same as you already do for `HomeScreen`.

Comment: Could you expand on this a bit? I added the { navigation } inside the AddCardScreen function and the `navigation={navigation}` as you have it. I have `const {navigation} = this.props.navigation` in the render() for AddCard.js. I'm receiving `TyperError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')` when I try the save button. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: You don't have a `navigation` inside the `this.props.navigation`. Either you do directly `this.props.navigation.navigate()` when you want to navigate, or if you want to destructure, you would do: `const { navigation } = this.props` and `navigation.navigate()` then.

Comment: The latter worked! Thank you so much, I appreciate it.